# Unexpected System failure of CentOS7 due to LVM partition not mounted

Tags: linux, logging, linux-kernel, centos7, lvm

I have a problem with my CentOS7 system installed in Intel NUC(Intel® Core™ i7-7567U CPU @ 3.50GHz × 4 ).
Last time i was not able to login to the system by any user or root password. Then I tried to rescue the password by reset root password. But it was not successful after many attempts.
During rescue mode, I found that the LVM partition 'home' was not activated in SSD (Crucial MX500 1TB: CT1000MX500SSD1) and log file has following error given below.

**What is cause of these error including LVM volume not mounted in CentOS7 (kernel 3.10.0-1062.12.1.el7.x86_64) while trying to login after many days? How to manage it so that it will not happen again?**

**Please help.**

*Output of lvdisplay is given below:-*

```
      --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/centos/home
  LV Name                home
  VG Name                centos
  LV UUID                ZhVKZ0-Oqwx-U3Jl-ukke-8cY6-dKQt-QX3W5g
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time ubuntu, 2020-01-05 20:05:17 +0530
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                522.31 GiB
  Current LE             133712
  Segments               2
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:2

[root@localhost log]# lsblk 
NAME            MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda               8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1            8:1    0   200M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2            8:2    0     1G  0 part /boot
└─sda3            8:3    0 930.1G  0 part 
  ├─centos-root 253:0    0   400G  0 lvm  /
  ├─centos-swap 253:1    0   7.8G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  └─centos-home 253:2    0 522.3G  0 lvm  /home
```

*Failed message in log file is given below:-*

```
messages-20200202:Jan 29 15:13:28 localhost journal: g_array_unref: assertion 'array' failed
messages-20200202:Jan 29 15:13:28 localhost journal: g_array_unref: assertion 'array' failed
messages-20200216:Feb 11 11:58:45 localhost journal: g_array_unref: assertion 'array' failed
messages-20200216:Feb 11 11:58:45 localhost journal: g_array_unref: assertion 'array' failed
```

messages-20200216:Feb 11 12:07:17 localhost journal: g_array_unref: assertion 'array' failed
messages-20200216:Feb 11 12:07:17 localhost journal: g_array_unref: assertion 'array' failed

and

```
[root@localhost log]# grep failed messages| cut -f3- -d ':'|cut -f2- -d' '|sort -u

localhost dracut:    microcode_ctl: kernel version "3.10.0-1062.12.1.el7.x86_64" failed early             load check for "intel-06-4f-01", skipping
localhost gdm: GLib: g_hash_table_find: assertion 'version == hash_table->version' failed
localhost gnome-keyring-daemon[2729]: failed to unlock login keyring on startup
localhost gnome-keyring-daemon[5458]: failed to unlock login keyring on startup
localhost journal: disabling plugin because: failed to coldplug amt: ME refused connection
localhost journal: disabling plugin because: failed to coldplug synapticsmst: MST firmware updating not supported by OEM
localhost journal: disabling plugin because: failed to startup dell: Firmware updating not supported
localhost journal: failed to call gs_plugin_refresh on odrs: [*/*/*/source/odrs/*] failed to download https://odrs.gnome.org/1.0/reviews/api/ratings: Connection terminated unexpectedly
localhost journal: failed to call gs_plugin_refresh on shell-extensions: [*/*/*/source/shell-extensions/*] failed to download https://extensions.gnome.org//static/extensions.json: Connection terminated unexpectedly
localhost journal: failed to connect to device: Failed to connect to missing device /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/xrandr_Dell_Inc__DELL_E2418HN_5RFY876Q0JKB_gdm_42
localhost journal: failed to get native mode status: Error reading from file: Input/output error
localhost journal: failed to set screen _ICC_PROFILE: Failed to open file “/var/lib/gdm/.local/share/icc/edid-7699f71e10e1e1f6308292efbe777a00.icc”: Permission denied
localhost journal: g_array_unref: assertion 'array' failed
localhost journal: g_dbus_proxy_call_finish_internal: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_PROXY (proxy)' failed
localhost journal: g_variant_get_va: assertion 'value != NULL' failed
localhost journal: g_variant_unref: assertion 'value != NULL' failed
localhost kernel: ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.RP04.PXSX] (Node ffff88073a265118), AE_NOT_FOUND (20130517/psparse-536)
localhost kernel: ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.RP04.PXSX] (Node ffff8c00ba26b118), AE_NOT_FOUND (20130517/psparse-536)
localhost kernel: ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.RP04.PXSX] (Node ffff90203a265118), AE_NOT_FOUND (20130517/psparse-536)
localhost kernel: ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.RP04.PXSX] (Node ffff9082ba265118), AE_NOT_FOUND (20130517/psparse-536)
localhost kernel: ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.RP04.PXSX] (Node ffff92ec3a262118), AE_NOT_FOUND (20130517/psparse-536)
localhost kernel: ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.RP04.PXSX] (Node ffff9443ba261118), AE_NOT_FOUND (20130517/psparse-536)
localhost kernel: ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.RP04.PXSX] (Node ffff95a0fa26c118), AE_NOT_FOUND (20130517/psparse-536)
localhost kernel: ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.RP04.PXSX] (Node ffff96f1ba265118), AE_NOT_FOUND (20130517/psparse-536)
localhost kernel: ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.RP04.PXSX] (Node ffff98997a267118), AE_NOT_FOUND (20130517/psparse-536)
localhost kernel: ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.RP04.PXSX] (Node ffff9b41fa265118), AE_NOT_FOUND (20130517/psparse-536)
localhost kernel: ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.RP04.PXSX] (Node ffff9db0fa265118), AE_NOT_FOUND (20130517/psparse-536)
localhost kernel: ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.RP04.PXSX] (Node ffff9e9fba261118), AE_NOT_FOUND (20130517/psparse-536)
localhost kernel: ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.RP08.PXSX] (Node ffff88073a266488), AE_NOT_FOUND (20130517/psparse-536)
localhost kernel: ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.RP08.PXSX] (Node ffff8c00ba26c488), AE_NOT_FOUND (20130517/psparse-536)
localhost kernel: ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.RP08.PXSX] (Node ffff90203a266488), AE_NOT_FOUND (20130517/psparse-536)
localhost kernel: ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.RP08.PXSX] (Node ffff9082ba266488), AE_NOT_FOUND (20130517/psparse-536)
localhost kernel: ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.RP08.PXSX] (Node ffff92ec3a263488), AE_NOT_FOUND (20130517/psparse-536)
localhost kernel: ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.RP08.PXSX] (Node ffff9443ba262488), AE_NOT_FOUND (20130517/psparse-536)
localhost kernel: ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.RP08.PXSX] (Node ffff95a0fa26d488), AE_NOT_FOUND (20130517/psparse-536)
localhost kernel: ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.RP08.PXSX] (Node ffff96f1ba266488), AE_NOT_FOUND (20130517/psparse-536)
localhost kernel: ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.RP08.PXSX] (Node ffff98997a268488), AE_NOT_FOUND (20130517/psparse-536)
localhost kernel: ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.RP08.PXSX] (Node ffff9b41fa266488), AE_NOT_FOUND (20130517/psparse-536)
localhost kernel: ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.RP08.PXSX] (Node ffff9db0fa266488), AE_NOT_FOUND (20130517/psparse-536)
localhost kernel: ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.RP08.PXSX] (Node ffff9e9fba262488), AE_NOT_FOUND (20130517/psparse-536)
localhost kernel: [drm] failed to retrieve link info, disabling eDP
localhost kernel: hid-generic 0003:413C:2113.0001: usb_submit_urb(ctrl) failed: -19
localhost kernel: pci 0000:01:00.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x2000]
localhost kernel: pci 0000:02:01.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x1000]
localhost kernel: pci 0000:02:02.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x1000]
localhost kernel: pci 0000:02:02.0: BAR 15: failed to assign [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
localhost kernel: pcieport 0000:01:00.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x2000]
localhost kernel: pcieport 0000:02:01.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x1000]
localhost kernel: pcieport 0000:02:02.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x1000]
localhost kernel: pcieport 0000:02:02.0: BAR 15: failed to assign [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
localhost kernel: thermal thermal_zone1: failed to read out thermal zone 1
localhost kernel: wlp58s0: failed to remove key (1, ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff) from hardware (-22)
localhost kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:39:00.0: Host halt failed, -19
localhost kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:39:00.0: Host not accessible, reset failed.
localhost lldpad: config file failed to load,
localhost NetworkManager[1425]: <warn>  [1582646846.5334] sup-iface: failed to cancel p2p connect: P2P cancel failed
localhost NetworkManager[1425]: <warn>  [1582646846.5338] supplicant: failed to set WFD IEs on wpa_supplicant: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: No such property
localhost NetworkManager[1429]: <warn>  [1582632750.1176] sup-iface: failed to cancel p2p connect: P2P cancel failed
localhost NetworkManager[1429]: <warn>  [1582632750.1181] supplicant: failed to set WFD IEs on wpa_supplicant: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: No such property
localhost NetworkManager[1430]: <warn>  [1582625137.7477] sup-iface: failed to cancel p2p connect: P2P cancel failed
localhost NetworkManager[1430]: <warn>  [1582625137.7477] supplicant: failed to set WFD IEs on wpa_supplicant: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: No such property
localhost NetworkManager[1431]: <warn>  [1582647800.3975] sup-iface: failed to cancel p2p connect: P2P cancel failed
localhost NetworkManager[1431]: <warn>  [1582647800.4014] supplicant: failed to set WFD IEs on wpa_supplicant: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: No such property
localhost NetworkManager[1432]: <warn>  [1582625829.1927] sup-iface: failed to cancel p2p connect: P2P cancel failed
localhost NetworkManager[1432]: <warn>  [1582625829.1943] supplicant: failed to set WFD IEs on wpa_supplicant: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: No such property
localhost NetworkManager[1432]: <warn>  [1582647271.2795] sup-iface: failed to cancel p2p connect: P2P cancel failed
localhost NetworkManager[1432]: <warn>  [1582647271.2798] supplicant: failed to set WFD IEs on wpa_supplicant: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: No such property
localhost NetworkManager[1433]: <warn>  [1582625731.2519] sup-iface: failed to cancel p2p connect: P2P cancel failed
localhost NetworkManager[1433]: <warn>  [1582625731.2520] supplicant: failed to set WFD IEs on wpa_supplicant: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: No such property
localhost NetworkManager[1434]: <warn>  [1582624667.2971] sup-iface: failed to cancel p2p connect: P2P cancel failed
localhost NetworkManager[1434]: <warn>  [1582624667.2971] supplicant: failed to set WFD IEs on wpa_supplicant: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: No such property
localhost NetworkManager[1434]: <warn>  [1582632328.6818] sup-iface: failed to cancel p2p connect: P2P cancel failed
localhost NetworkManager[1434]: <warn>  [1582632328.6819] supplicant: failed to set WFD IEs on wpa_supplicant: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: No such property
localhost NetworkManager[1437]: <warn>  [1582631756.9007] sup-iface: failed to cancel p2p connect: P2P cancel failed
localhost NetworkManager[1437]: <warn>  [1582631756.9008] supplicant: failed to set WFD IEs on wpa_supplicant: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: No such property
localhost NetworkManager[3190]: <warn>  [1582624727.5623] sup-iface: failed to cancel p2p connect: P2P cancel failed
localhost NetworkManager[3190]: <warn>  [1582624727.5623] supplicant: failed to set WFD IEs on wpa_supplicant: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: No such property
localhost NetworkManager[3242]: <warn>  [1582631895.7613] sup-iface: failed to cancel p2p connect: P2P cancel failed
localhost NetworkManager[3242]: <warn>  [1582631895.7616] supplicant: failed to set WFD IEs on wpa_supplicant: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: No such property
localhost org.gnome.Shell.CalendarServer: gnome-shell-calendar-server[3983]: Lost (or failed to acquire) the name org.gnome.Shell.CalendarServer - exiting
localhost org.gnome.Shell.CalendarServer: gnome-shell-calendar-server[5779]: Lost (or failed to acquire) the name org.gnome.Shell.CalendarServer - exiting
```

Comment: StackOverflow is focused on software development. You will have better chances to get answer at [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you keep lvm backup file in an non-lvm partition, in your case /boot will do.

to create a backup you do

> sudo vgcfgbackup -f /boot/lvmback /dev/centos

centos is your VG name

then in case of trouble, just run

> sudo vgcfgrestore centos -v -f ./boot/lvmback;
>   sudo vgchange -a y